# Dynamically Paginating .epub files in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am loading files from an `.epub` into `UIWebView`s for display. At the moment, the `.epub` is divided into individual files for each chapter. To display the chapters, I am just loading these files into `UIWebView`. I am trying to figure out how to break these down into pages depending on font size, styling, etc. It's proving difficult, as iOS only accesses the `UIWebView` content indirectly. Is there a standard method for breaking it up?

I'm thinking about grabbing full chapter content out of a page with JS, then breaking each chapter down into pages based on line length and lines per page, but that seems sort of crazy, and I'm having trouble returning it to a `UIWebView` as valid html or javascript code. (The text contains single quotes, etc.)

Comment: Did you found a solution ? I have exactly the same need.

Answer (score 1):

Use UIWebView Pagination :)

```
myWebView.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight;
myWebView.paginationBreakingMode = UIWebPaginationBreakingModePage;
myWebView.gapBetweenPages = 50;
```

For font scaling, you need to inject css thru javascript for webkit's font scaling property

```
http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-text-size-adjust
```